# How to rewrite clean URLs with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have the following `.htaccess` rule for language setting:

```
RewriteRule ^en/?$ /index.php?lang=en [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^fr/?$ /index.php?lang=fr [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^de/?$ /index.php?lang=de [NC,L,R=301]
```

However, when I input the clean URL for example `example.com/fr`, then the URL redirects to `example.com/index.php?lang=fr` in the browser.

How can the URL remain clean?

I tried the following, but it does not work either, the URL does not remain clean:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/? /index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^en/?$ /index.php?lang=en [NC,L,R=301]
> RewriteRule ^fr/?$ /index.php?lang=fr [NC,L,R=301]
> RewriteRule ^de/?$ /index.php?lang=de [NC,L,R=301]
> ```

To prevent the *external redirect* you just need to remove the `R` flag. This then becomes an *internal rewrite* and the URL remains as `example.com/fr` in the browsers address bar. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^en/?$ /index.php?lang=en [NC,L]
```

To make this more concise when the number of languages are limited then you can combine these three directives into one using *alternation* in the regex:

```
 RewriteRule ^(en|fr|de)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1 [NC,L]
```

`$1` is a backreference to the captured language id: "en", "fr" or "de".

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing as any erroneous 301s are likely to have been cached by the browser.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/? /index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
> ```

This would never match in a `.htaccess` context, simply because of the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. So this wouldn't have done anything. (You may have seen a cached response if the request was still redirected?). This should read:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) /index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

The trailing `/?` on the pattern is superfluous. However, this matches any path segment. eg. `example.com/about` or `example.com/foo/bar`, etc.